# Is it possible to allow BP Group Admins to Set which Menu Tab they would like to have as their Default landing page?

Tags: buddypress, tabs

Is it possible to allow BP Group Admins to Set which Menu Tab they would like to have as their Default landing page when people enter their Group like Activity Stream or Documents etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it programmatically like this:  [What's the easiest way to change the default landing page for BuddyPress groups?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/44863/whats-the-easiest-way-to-change-the-default-landing-page-for-buddypress-groups)

The answer there could be expanded into a plugin that would provide a UI for group admins (and a means of storing preferences on a group-by-group basis), though this would take a bit of engineering using the BP Group Extension API: http://codex.buddypress.org/developer-docs/group-extension-api/

Comment: Thanks! would it take alot of coding/work to do?
Can I pay you to make it for me? :)

Comment: It will take a fair amount of work, just because building settings UI is generally a pain in the butt. But it is not difficult, and the Group Extension API really does give you most of the tools you need. I'm afraid I'm not taking on any contract work at the moment :)